# FXML: ComboBox CellFactory

Tags: javafx, combobox, fxml

I have a `ComboBox` that I bound it's `items` property to a list of `Model`s. This `Model` class has a `String` member called `name`. How can I have only the `name`s in the `ComboBox`? I thought of using `CellFactory` but for some reason it's not working.

*Note*: I want to do it in `FXML`

Here's the code:

FXML:

```
<ComboBox  items="$Controller.models">
    <cellFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="name"/> 
    </cellFactory>
</ComboBox>
```

Controller:

```
private final List<Model> models = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public List<Model> getModels() {
    return models;
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model{
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `PropertyValueFactory` is not an implementation of a `cellFactory`, it's an implementation of a `cellValueFactory`. A cell factory is a factory (i.e. it's executable code that implements an interface): you cannot define such a thing in FXML, you have to do it in the controller.

Comment: is it the best way to do the job?

Comment: It's pretty much the only way.

Comment: Actually I found a better way (or I claim I have). I overrided the toString method to return the name member, since I believe the comboBox uses it to retrieve data from the Model class. And it works.

Comment: That works, but it's not a very good approach imho. In general you might need the `toString()` method for other reasons (particularly for debugging); so it's bad practice to constrain it for the purposes of how you want the object displayed in your UI. You are effectively putting *display* code (how you want the object to appear in the UI) in the *model* class (which is supposed to just represent the data).